# React-Native StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-redux

Ok guys, so I have a question, I am new to react-native development and got a problem with a StackNavigator. When I press a button meant to navigate of the current screen, it gives me an error like this one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPxqg.jpg)

This is the code I am using and I can't get it to work,

```
   static navigationOptions = {
     title: 'Welcome',
     };

    <Button
      onPress={() => navigate('News')}
      title="News"
    />

    const NewsApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Splash },
    News: { screen: News }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the render function you have to extract navigator like this:

```
render()
{
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigate('News')}
      title="News"
    />
  )
}
```

getting started with stack navigation:

```
//First Screen

      import {
      StackNavigator,
    } from 'react-navigation';
//Added screens to navigate.    
    const BasicApp = StackNavigator({
      Main: {screen: MainScreen},
      Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
    });
//Second screen (Main Screen)
//This is a welcome screen which appears first in the route declared in the previous code
    class MainScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
      };
      render() {
      //constant for navigation 
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <Button
            title="Go to Jane's profile"
            onPress={() =>
            navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })//Navigate to Profile with name
            }
          />
        );
      }
    }

//Third screen (Profile screen)

    class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: navigation.state.params.name, //extracted name from the params
      });
      render() {
        const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;//used to goBack prop
        return (
          <Button
            title="Go back"
            onPress={() => goBack()} 
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Cheers :)

Comment: This is the first part 


export default  class Splash extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Welcome',
 };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = 'this.props.navigation';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Image style={styles.imglogo}
        source={{uri: '.....'}}
       />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          News
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('News')}
          title="News"
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

Comment: This is second part 
class Chat extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = 'this.props.navigation';
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const NewsApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Splash },
  News: { screen: Chat }
});

Comment: why did you kept const { navigate } = 'this.props.navigation' in quotes? remove the quotes and again run the code

Comment: after I removed quotes it says undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: please, can you add the above code to the question and explain me on which button click your application crashes?

Comment: for the sake of explanation, i am adding the code for stack navigation from the scratch to my answer so that it helps you find your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed trying to navigate from the component you created it in, you won't have access to the navigator since it only injects navigation to anything inside `NewsApp`.

You should handle the back press inside the topmost component in the navigation stack. If you need to however have control of the navigation in places such as the one you have then perhaps implementing redux would be a good solution for you.